# get python 2.7 packages and install them for python 3.6

Tags: python, pip

I'm starting to move to python 3 and the headache of installing all of the packages from 2.7 to 3.6 one by one gives me a headache just thinking about it. Is there a library to do this automatically?

Answer (score 1):

Use `pip freeze > requirements.txt` to create a file listing the Python 2 packages you have installed then `pip3 install -r requirements.txt --upgrade` to install the same packages for Python 3.

Comment: One problem with that is it doesn't know some modules are not compatible with python 3. One example is beautifulsoup... i need to install `beautifulsoup4 ` now, but pip freeze gives me v3

Comment: i guess there is no database to help people with the transition? people have to figure out what version to install module by module?